# Is State monad needed/useful in a language with mutable (local) variables (such as Scala)?

Tags: scala, haskell, state-monad

I understand that in Haskell the State monad is useful because there are no mutable variables (unless we are in the IO monad).

However, what is the deal with Scala ? Is State Monad useful in a language where there are mutable variables ?

In some sense all the State Monad allows is to [use some local mutable variables within the Monad context](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Brian-Beckman-The-Zen-of-Expressing-State-The-State-Monad). For example here:

```
 newtype Labeled anytype = Labeled (S -> (S, anytype))

 instance Monad Labeled where

   return contents = Labeled (\st -> (st, contents))

   Labeled fst0 >>= fany1 = 
     Labeled $ \st0 -> 
       let (st1, any1) = fst0 st0 
           Labeled fst1 = fany1 any1
       in fst1 st1 

 mlabel :: Tr anytype -> Lt anytype
 mlabel tr = let Labeled mt = mkm tr
             in snd (mt 0) 

 mkm :: Tr anytype -> Labeled (Lt anytype)

 mkm (Lf x)
   = updateState >>= \n -> return $ Lf (n,x)

 mkm (Br l r)
   = mkm l >>= \l' ->
     mkm r >>= \r' ->
     return $ (Br l' r')

 updateState :: Labeled S
 updateState =  Labeled (\n -> ((n+1),n))

 main = print $ mlabel tr1
```

This code would be much simpler (3-4 lines) using mutable variables in Scala. Something like:
`case class Tr (...)`

`case class LTr (...)`

`def labelTree = (... recursive call ... )`

where `labelTree` is using local mutable variables to store the current state of the label.

I don't really see the usefulness of State Monads in Scala. Why would anyone use State Monad in Scala ? Are there any good use cases for it ?

The only use case I can imagine if the stateful computation is complex and is composed from several State Monads, but at that point I am not sure how useful it is to use State Monad in contrast to plain old functional programming and explicit argument passing (instead of implicit argument passing which is what the State Monad is).

Comment: This is probably a matter of opinion. But some food for thought: Haskell can do mutable references (IORef, STRef, etc.), so any reason you give for not using State in Scala is just as valid for Haskell. So why do Haskellers use State?

Comment: I'd also guess it's not so useful in a language with mutability. Maybe one could use a state monad to document that a specific subroutine mutates only the state of a few variables, but leaves the rest of the state untouched. Perhaps it is not worth the effort, especially if the state monad is implemented as a function, hence is less efficient than plain mutable variables (at least without optimization).

Comment: @user2297560 maybe they don't wanna be in the IO monad, for some reason  ?

Comment: It don't think it's true that state monad is more widely used than the zillion mutable ref and array types e.g. `Data.IORef`, `Data.STRef` `Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar`, `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable` and so on.

Comment: One reason I sometimes use `State` instead of `IORef` is that the state is persistent, making it easier to speculatively execute an action and roll back any changes if it fails.

Answer (score 5):

When composing stateful actions in Haskell, there is an idiom in which actions only demand to know the bare minimum of state needed to accomplish their tasks, and then each action is [zoomed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#t:Zoom) into a composite "global state". For example:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

succInt :: StateT Int IO String
succInt = do
    modify succ
    return "Incr an Int!"

succChar :: StateT Char IO String
succChar = do
    modify succ
    return "Incr a Char!"

type GlobalState = (Char,[Int])

composite :: StateT GlobalState IO (String,String)
composite = do
    r1 <- zoom _1 succChar
    r2 <- zoom (_2.traversed) succInt
    return (r1,r2)
```

If we execute the example like this:

```
ghci> runStateT composite ('a',[1,5,7])
```

The result is

```
(("Incr a Char!","Incr an Int!Incr an Int!Incr an Int!"),('b',[2,6,8]))
```

I think the "zooming" of the states into bigger states would be more difficult to accomplish with mutable variables.

Comment: That said, the  "monad-unlift-ref" package provides a reference-based state monad in Haskell http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-unlift-ref

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is nice stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The great advantage of State monad on mutable variables (that is, in a functional programming mindset) is reference transparency.

A chunk of code using the State monad is more easily unit-testable, more maintainable, and less error prone than the equivalent using `var`s, because the logic of the code will not depend on where and when this code is run.

Another viewpoint of the same issue is that the State monad encodes in the type system the fact that a value is mutable, while a `var` gives no such information.

**EDIT**

However, the state monad is probably always less efficient than mutable variables, because it adds another level of abstraction between the written code and the compiled output. But this can be said for most of functional constructs, so this is not a real argument for the use of `var`s in functional scala code.

Comment: Right but if the `vars` are used **locally** (is in the State Monad)? Inside a function ? Like in the example above ? You can inject the state and extract the state from a function (that uses local variables) just as well, just like from a State monad, so it is just as testable/maintainable/etc as the local solution. A function where the state is hidden is just as referentially transparent as a State Monad because you cannot pass around a function "half evaluated".

Comment: That's becoming a more opinionated issue, much like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995875/where-should-one-draw-the-line-between-functional-programming-and-imperative-pro

Comment: On the "always less efficient", I'm unsure. I think one could implement a Scala State monad using mutability, recovering most of the performance.

Comment: Back to square one.

Comment: @chi, I meant "at most only as efficient as".

Comment: @jhegedus referential transparency is lost inside the implementation of the function where you use your `var`. If it is a small straightforward function, it will probably be useful and increase performances, but if you start doing more complicated stuff, you might need help from the compiler (with types) or from tests, to ensure that everything goes as planned. The (opinionated) question that remains is "Where do you draw the line?"

Comment: Yeah, but what should the type system remind me of ? That a function is using a local `var` on the inside (which is not visible on the outside) ? `mlabel :: Tr anytype -> Lt anytype` is a pure function. Who wants to know how a pure function is implemented on the inside ?

Comment: It would be nice to see an example where the State Monad is clearly more suitable/shorter/composable/in any way "better" than a local `var`.

Comment: @jhegedus a state monad program is often shorter and simpler than one using a var. A var/ref program must either take the pregiven var as an argument, or else contain initialization of the var. If the latter it does not compose. It is also more complex by referring explicitly to the var throughout. A `State` program just starts getting and putting and modifying implicit state. Later when you run it, after composing it with other like programs, you runState with an initial state.It also permits composability by use of `zoom` as @danidiaz points out.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how composability is simpler with a `State` program, you can use monadic combinators and whatnot, such as sequence and so on. Composability is indeed a valid argument in favor of a `State` program